# Convert XML, Layout, Style files into aar file. Android

Tags: android, aar

I am relatively new to android programming and would like to know if I could archive a module. Meaning if i have a fully functioning module with it's layout files, images and some java files, will it be possible for me to archive that send them to other people so they can start using the same module as an aar file in their project?

Thanks in advance

Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a slightly silly question. I have done my research. The aar does help you do this completely. All xml layout files, drawable files and other resources can be imported to other projects through aar